# Compare two dataframes based on combination of columns in each dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two dataframes named `dfA` and `dfB`.
I want to compare `(col1A AND col2A)` of `dfA` with `(col1B AND col2B)` of `dfB`. And return only those rows of `dfB` where they match together.
i.e.

```
(col1A and col12A) =(col1B and col2B)
```

What is the most efficient way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the most efficient, but here is a way to do it:

**Merge the two tables:**

```
df = dfB.merge(dfA, left_on=['col1B', 'col2B'], right_on=['col1A', 'col2A'], how='inner')
```

**Remove the columns from dfA:**

```
df.drop(['col1A', 'col2A'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```